# Can we add and update on same column in PHP at MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query("insert into support values('null','$status','$sbj','$message','$userid','$user','','','$date','')", $dbc) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

$index = mysql_insert_id();
$inci = '1' . $index;

echo "$inci";

mysql_query("UPDATE support SET incidentno='$inci' WHERE index='$index'",$dbc) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

printf("<h2>your incident id is: %d\n</h2>", $inci) ;

echo $inci;
```

Comment: this would be only possible by using a trigger on that table

Comment: @HeenaGoyal I am unsure how to answer your question.  However, you really shouldn't use the `mysql_*` functions. I personally recommend `Pdo`, and there are also `mysqli_*` functions (notice the i) which might be more familiar to what you are currently doing.  Also, `or die` isn't exactly good error handling.  Maybe this is just an example, but it looks like an actual code snippet.

Comment: And don't put `values('null', ...`. You probably want to write `values(null, ...` there.

Comment: @rabudde: how to use trigger?

Comment: @ypercube: ok bt by doing this i couldnt get d ans

Comment: @LeviMorrison: i dont the function which u r sayng to use plz tell me actual syntax

Comment: provide full column names on doing `INSERT`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add trigger on table (use MySQL console or something similar), here is a full example with a test table names `support`

```
CREATE TABLE `support` (
    `index` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `incidentno` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `login` (
    `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `section` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `generate_incidentno` BEFORE INSERT ON `support`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.incidentno = CONCAT(CASE (SELECT section FROM login WHERE username=NEW.username)
        WHEN 'dehli' THEN '1'
        ELSE '2'
    END
    , (
        SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'support'
    ));
END$$
DELIMITER ;


INSERT INTO login VALUES ('user1','dehli'),('user2','dehli'),('user3','other');
INSERT INTO support VALUES (NULL,'user1','');
INSERT INTO support VALUES (NULL,'user1','');
INSERT INTO support VALUES (NULL,'user2','');
INSERT INTO support VALUES (NULL,'user3','');
INSERT INTO support VALUES (NULL,'user3','');
SELECT * FROM support;


id  username   incidentno
1   user1      11
2   user1      12
3   user2      13
4   user3      24
5   user3      25
```

as you can see, all is fine

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. This is a DML trigger in MySQL. It has to be created in MySQL. The only thing to do in PHP is to execute your `mysql_query("insert [...]");`

Comment: Could not connect: Can't update table 'support' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. giving this error

Comment: Did you commented out the `UPDATE` part?

Comment: please provide full `CREATE TABLE support [...]` in your original post

Comment: m using phpmyadmin so i have created table visualy. It has 10 fields ISt is index which is autoincremented last is incidentno. which we want to create from index

Comment: see me edited post, I've created a test table, created the trigger, inserted some data and all is fine - `incidentno` is filled correctly. so check your table structure and PHP code, I can't help you else.

Comment: wat is d name of database you have used?

Comment: I've created a test database for me purposes. You have to use your database that contains the table `support`

Comment: +-------+-----------+------------+
| index | something | incidentno |
+-------+-----------+------------+
|     1 | blabla    |            |
|     2 | testtest  |            |
+-------+-----------+------------+

Comment: incidentno field is showng empty i have tried d same commands

Comment: What does `SHOW TRIGGERS;` show when you execute this command in your database?

Comment: rows are affected bt when i select table there is empty row of incidentno

Comment: i have checkd the command prompt they are showing triggers already exist wt is d command to delete them?

Comment: I don't know what triggers exists on your tables, but for now there has to be only one trigger on table `support`. So delete all triggers on this table and re-execute my trigger script.

Comment: wat is d quey for deleting triggers?

Comment: sorry, but you can do a little homework, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-trigger.html

Comment: thnx a lot  dear... i have got it...! realy thnx @rabudde

Comment: i thnk nw u gonna kill me @rabudde bt my main concept is dat anythng else bt we have do chnges at sever side.. bt i want to use if else in dat for particular cndtion its prefix is 1 for any other cndition its prefix wil 2.. nw hw can i achieve it?

Comment: condition is on username for some particular user which is foreign key of another table"login" if their section=delhi then their prefix is 1 else their prefix is 2.. section is column of table "login"..

Comment: See my edited post and have a look at changed table schema and changed trigger. Important is, that every new row in table `support` has to be inserted seperately. Read the changed trigger exactly and try to understand.

Comment: thnx dear.. i have got ma sol.